# Sort array ascending and descending reactjs

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I'm trying to sort my data from ascending to descending. This is my code:

```
  const onSort = (sortKey) => {
  let sortCustomer = [...customers];
  sortCustomer.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) { return -1; }
    if(a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) { return 1; }
    return 0;
  })
  setcustomers(sortCustomer);
```

}

The ascending is working but the descending is not working.

Comment: Consult the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

your sorter function is just for ascending order, for descending order you should do this:

```
const onSort = (sortKey) => {
  let sortCustomer = [...customers];
  sortCustomer.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) { return -1; }
    if(a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) { return 1; }
    return 0;
  })

  // create a variable to determine whether to use ascending or descending order
  if (order === 'desc') {
    sortCustomer.reverse()
  }

  setcustomers(sortCustomer);
}
```

Comment: 'order' is not defined

Comment: You have to define it yourself, I don’t know your application logic, so this is just a dummy code

Answer (score 0):

The function you're passing in to `sort()` will ALWAYS sort in ascending order, why would you expect it to sort in descending order?

```
.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) { return -1; }
    if(a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) { return 1; }
    return 0;
  })
```

To sort it in descending order, it would need to do the following:

```
.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) { return 1; }
    if(a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) { return -1; }
    return 0;
  })
```